# Knitr behavior with date objects

Tags: r, date, knitr

Say I have the following object inside a knitr chunk:

```
df <- as.Date(c("2013-10-01", "2013-10-02", "2013-10-03"))
```

Now, when I try to run this:

```
`r min(df)`  # that would be \Sexpr{min(df)} for a TeX file
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in Math.Date(x) : abs not defined for "Date" objects
Calls: knit ... .inline.hook -> format_sci -> vapply -> FUN -> Math.Date

Execution halted

knitr terminated with status 1
```

Is this a bug? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this will qualify as an answer, but yes, that does seem to be a bug--I wonder what other classes are affected!

A simple but possibly inconvenient workaround would be to convert your output to "character" first. In other words, try something like:

> ````
> ```{r}
> df <- as.Date(c("2013-10-01", "2013-10-02", "2013-10-03"))
> ```
>
> Here's a paragraph with `r as.character(min(df))`.
> ````

Comment: Workaround works. Since I won't be doing calculations with dates this time, that is good enough for me. Thanks, Ananda!

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio thanks for the report; it has been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr)